# TinyMCE: How to insert content and select it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

How does one insert, or better, replace the current selection with some content and then select it?

Here's my text: *Hello `nice` world!*

As you can see `nice` is selected by the user. Now he clicks a button and this code is run:

```
editor.execCommand('mceReplaceContent', 'nasty');
```

This works just fine, the result is: *Hello nasty world*, but nothing is selected.

How do I make it automatically select `nasty` in the result content?

This seems like a very natural thing for one to want to do, but can't seem to find a straight-forward solution. I need this to work in mostly two cases 1) I am wrapping the selected text in a f.e. `span` element or 2) I am removing the wrapping `span` element.

I know there are better ways of dealing with nodes, but I'm more concerned about the pure text scenario right now.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I am using TinyMCE 3 not 4.

Comment: @ПашинськийВіктор I can't really remember, it's been 7 years, but I think the only way involved dealing with the caret position or something like that. I remember it was a nightmare and eventually I gave up. I'm pretty sure TinyMCE 5 has way better ways of dealing with this now.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm using Wordpress = TinyMCE 4. It's still nightmare. Even simple sings usually works strange.

Answer (score 2):

I found this in [the docs (API 3.x)](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:property.tinymce.Editor.selection)

```
// Sets some contents to the current selection in the editor
tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.setContent('Some contents');

// Selects the first paragraph found
tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.select(tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.select('p')[0]);
```

The `setContent` function does practically the same as `execCommand('mceReplaceContent')`. I did not found something like the easy DOM properties `selectionStart` & `selectionEnd`.

Comment: `setContent` will not add an Undo level like `mceReplaceContent`, and I need to select the inserted text, which might be just a word inside of the paragraph. I don't need to select the entire paragraph.